# Karma/Reputation Plugin for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rubygems

I am looking for a karma (reputation) plugin or gem for Ruby on Rails.  Preferably one that was integrated many of the best practices and research around the topic of community management & development.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [vote fu](http://github.com/peteonrails/vote_fu/).

Howver my advice would be the following : don't rely every time on plugins.
For some things that could be completely different from one app to an other, relying on a plugin can sometimes makes things harder to implement.

Comment: is this plugin compatible with rails3?

Comment: Last commit : August 2009. I wouldn't use it.

Comment: Replaced by thumbs_up - https://github.com/brady8/thumbs_up

Answer (score 2):

**Update for 2012**

[merit](https://github.com/tute/merit) seems to be the new kid on the block!

For a (hopefully) all-time list, goto [Ruby Toolbox - Reputation Engines](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Reputation_Engines) .

Comment: ruby toolbox is missing https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/, also a good one